# Творительный падеж от слова «суда́рь»

Tags: орфоэпия, славянизмы

Есть слово «суда́рь» — плат, пелена.

Как будет звучать от него творительный падеж? «сударём»? «сударе́м»? «суда́рем»?

Я понимаю, что есть похожее слово «государь», от которого творительный падеж «госуда́рем», но в случае ударений «проверочные слова» зачастую не работают.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Есть слово «суда́рь» — плат, пелена.
>
> Как будет звучать от него творительный падеж? «сударём»? «сударе́м»?
>   «суда́рем»?

Правилен третий вариант: суда́рем.

Ударение в этом слове во всех падежных формах остаётся на втором слоге.

См. **"Орфографический словарь"** на Грамоте.ру:

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=Сударь&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&all=x)

Comment: На основании чего Вы считаете, что _ударение в этом слове во всех падёжных формах остаётся на втором слоге_?

Comment: @pantlmn Так устроен "Орфографический словарь". Введите для примера слово "рука". В нём будут выделены все случаи изменения ударения по падежам. (К сожалению, не все словари придерживаются этого правила. "Большой толковый словарь" не отметил винительный падеж для слова "рука".)

Comment: _На основании чего Вы считаете, что ударение в этом слове во всех падежных формах остаётся на втором слоге?_=== Вечером буду дома, приведу выдержку из бумажного словаря.

Comment: _pantlmn: На основании чего Вы считаете, что ударение в этом слове во всех падежных формах остаётся на втором слоге?_ === На основании обычной словарной практики. _"**Если отдельные падежи отличаются от родительного падежа ед. числа** по образованию, **по месту ударения** или затруднительны в орфографическом отношении,  то соответствующие формы отмечаются в словаре" (из предисловия к тринадцатому изданию "Орфографического словаря русского языка"). Отсутствие в словаре форм других косвенных падежей говорит о том, что ударение в этих формах совпадает с ударением в форме род. падежа ед. ч.

Comment: pantlmn, почему в падЁжных формах? Или это юмор такой?

Comment: _Инна: pantlmn, почему в падЁжных формах? Или это юмор такой?_ === Это не pantlmn накосячил. Он только процитировал мою первоначальную редакцию ответа, а в ней действительно  было Ё. Писал я на ходу, с айпада. И умный айпад написал слово _падежных_ с Ё, а я проглядел это. Заметил только тогда, когда увидел Ё в комментарии pantlmn. Свой ответ я сразу же поправил, а вот комментарии-то не поправишь... Время для правки ушло.

Answer (score 1):

суд**а**рь, -я (покровец, церк.)
[**Полный орфографический словарь русского языка. 2012**](https://slovar.cc/rus/orfo-rus/919879.html)

Действительно, ударение падает на второй слог во всех формах: **а** выделена  как ударная (а **я** в родительном падеже — нет).
Так же склоняется "господарь": [господ**а**рь, -я](https://slovar.cc/rus/orfo-rus/810534.html).

Для сравнения:
фон**а**рь, -**я** (ударение в Р. п. — на последний слог).
[**Полный орфографический словарь русского языка. 2012**](https://slovar.cc/rus/orfo-rus/932350.html)